# Input type text fields are repeating after unchecking the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have check boxes called as Firstname, Lastname and Email. I have to display the input type after clicking on the check box or if unchecked then remove the check box.

Also, I am trying to get the label of check box which is selected but I am not getting it.

Would you help me in this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_text_type").click(function() {
    if ($('.add_text_type').is(":checked")) {
      var get_label = $('label[for="' + +$(this).attr('id') + '"]').text();
      $("#items").append('<div><label class=' + get_label + '></label><input type="text" name="input[]"></div>');
    } else {
      //what login I have to use here when unchecked check box
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_email_type").click(function() {
    if ($('.add_email_type').is(":checked")) {
      $("#items").append('<div><input type="email" name="input[]"></div>');
    } else {
      //what login I have to use here when unchecked check box
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_text_type" id="get_first_name">
<label for="get_first_name">First Name</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_text_type" id="get_last_name">
<label for="get_last_name">Last Name</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_email_type" id="get_email">
<label for="get_email">Email</label>
```

Comment: please add the element with id items in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to give the `div` elements that you append the `id` of the checkbox as a `class`, so that they can be easily identified when you need to remove them.

You can also DRY up the code by providing the `type` of the `input` to add as a `data` attribute on the checkbox which can be read in the `change` event handler, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".add_input").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#items").append('<div class="' + this.id + '"><input type="' + $(this).data('type') + '" name="input[]" placeholder="' + $(this).next('label').text() + '" /></div>');
    } else {
      $('#items').find('.' + this.id).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_input" id="get_first_name" data-type="text">
<label for="get_first_name">First Name</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_input" id="get_last_name" data-type="text">
<label for="get_last_name">Last Name</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_input" id="get_email" data-type="email">
<label for="get_email">Email</label>

<div id="items"></div>
```

Comment: It's working superbly. Thanks for the help.Appreciate your response within a minute.

Comment: I just want to know If I have to use select type then how can I use it?

Comment: For select you would probably be best to create a new function, as that's a completely different HTML structure; different tag name, attributes, child elements etc.

Comment: Please, can you help me in that also?

Comment: I'd suggest you start a new question for it

Comment: My new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054048/how-to-display-the-textarea-and-select-tag-after-selecting-the-check-box

Comment: Can you help me in above link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153772/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: I am still facing the issue. Please, can you help me out in above link?