# How to display the textarea and select tag after selecting the check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting these issues in my code.

1) I have to display the select dropdown and textarea after clicked on the check box.

2) I have to display the male and female option after checked on gender check box.

I am using data type in HTML for select dropdown and textarea. If any user clicked on state checkbox then the select dropdown will appear and if clicked on address then textarea will appear.

I am able to use input type text, checkbox, radio, email but not able to display the drop-down and textarea.

Would you help me out in this?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".add_input").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#items").append('<div class="' + this.id + '"> <input type="' + $(this).data('type') + '" name="input[]" placeholder="' + $(this).next('label').text() + '" /></div>');
    } else {
      $('#items').find('.' + this.id).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_input" id="get_select" data-type="select"><label for="get_select">State</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_input" id="get_textarea" data-type="textarea"><label for="get_textarea">Address</label>

<!--gender-->
<input type="checkbox" name="check-fields" class="add_input" id="get_radio" data-type="radio"><label for="get_radio">Gender</label>
<input type="radio" name="check-fields" id="get_radio" value="male">male
<input type="radio" name="check-fields" id="get_radio" value="female">female
<span id="items"></span>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the issue is? You don't know how to implement this?

Comment: The css attribute `display:block`and 'none`help you to avoid writing html with Javascript.

Comment: A few days back I upload on the question regarding the same issue. which is working for text, checkbox and email but that is not working for select and textarea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052531/input-type-text-fields-are-repeating-after-unchecking-the-checkbox/46052715#46052715

Comment: @reporter, with the help of display: block, I can do for gender but How can I make the select and textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(function() {
$('.radio').hide();
  $(".add_input").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#items").append('<div class="' + this.id + '"> <input type="' + $(this).data('type') + '" name="input[]" placeholder="' + $(this).next('label').text() + '" /></div>');
    } else {
      $('#items').find('.' + this.id).remove();
    }
  });
   $("#get_textarea").change(function() {
     if (this.checked) {
      $("#items").append('<div class="' + this.id + '"><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></div>');
     } else {
      $('#items').find('.' + this.id).remove();
    }
   });
  $("#get_radio").change(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $('.radio').show();
    }else{
     $('.radio').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a06x8f7d/1/).

Comment: @NarendraVerma I also made some modification in your html.. just check the fiddle..

Answer (score 1):

That's because select and text area form elements are not created using the  tag. I suggest you go back and look up how they are created. You will have to modify your code a bit to make it happen. More so for the select tag than the text area though.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Edit:
If you're going to create HTML instead of hiding/showing the HTML, I suggest checking to make sure that the tag ID you're creating doesn't already exist before creating it.

Comment: Yes, I am creating and ids are different